# How to protect the lace holes of a shoe from the lace without an eyelet?

Tags: shoes

Many shoes now-a-days, even the branded ones have some lace-holes without [eyelets](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=eyelets&client=firefox-b&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwilsv2o1arOAhUHpY8KHfH9DugQ_AUICCgB&biw=1569&bih=811). Each time the shoe laces are tied, the lace tears into the shoe.

[image]

Eyelets are only available in [bunches which are too expensive](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=eyelet) to buy for a requirement of four eyelets.

Sometimes the eyelet comes off too.

[image]

**Is there any other way to protect the lace holes from getting torn?**

Comment: What is the brand? I'd like to avoid this cost-cutting cheap manufacturer.

Comment: Don't worry; you won't encounter this brand at where you stay. The one in the pic is "Camro". The branded one I'm talking of is "Bata", which had only two eyelets loosely fixed on each shoe. Bata is sold at almost the price of Adidas or Reebok, but Camro is 5 times cheaper. (on a side note, actually the bigger brands should also be priced lower if they didn't splurge on adverts)

Comment: I know Bata. Better than that, I went to school with the son of the person who owns/owned Bata.

Comment: The blue-grey shoe above was purchased from Bata. It had eyelets only on the first lace-hole, and even that came off in a few months. So if shoe manufacturers are having to cut costs so much to beat competition, then the only other options we have are to buy from the competition or find a solution to the eyelet problem.

Comment: They look practically new. I'd take them back and complain. The eyelet is a cheap one-piece grommet. You have nothing to lose by bringing it back to the store, find the Bata facebook site, and complain that you have a "lemon" manufacture fault with the shoe. Use some great pictures like these. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to lace shoes for proper fit. (a technique to use for the eyelet style)

Proper shoe lacing prevents unnecessary stress on the eyelets (the small holes for the lace) and the counters (backs of the shoes). Here are a number of ways to lace shoes.

https://www.aofas.org/.../Lacing-Techniques-for-Proper-Shoe-Fit.aspx

Dress shoes often have leather to lace unreinforced eyelet treatment. There are a number of ways to make attractive lacing patterns here.

http://www.ties.com/how-to-tie-dress-shoes

You can also buy aftermarket self-backing reinforced eyelets to install yourself. While the link takes you to a source that might be more than you want to order, it is a possibility. A shoe repair station may give or sell you a lesser amount for your pair. Get a few extras for other eyelets, too. This is increasing the cost of the pair you already bought. You can blame the manufacturers for passing the cost on to you after the sale. Avoid one-piece "grommets" which are weak and split easily. Ask for two-piece ones that are made well and don't tear the shoe or the lace.

http://www.shoe-eyelets.com/index.html

First and foremost, avoid round hard laces that don't distribute the stress evenly. Substitute and use a flat soft fabric lace.

The maximum tension is exerted at the eyelets where you pull. If the lace across the toe is too loose, pulling the laces hard at the top exerts minimal force to the lace tension at the toe.

After the laces appear the way you find most attractive, begin to tighten them by taking up the slack length starting with the toe and working your way up from there.

When pulling shoelaces tight, pull outwards rather than upwards, to lessen friction against the holes.

Pull firmly and evenly and don't tug quickly on the lace ends.

Tie the lace with an [Ian Knot](http://www.fieggen.com/shoelace/ianknot.htm) which uses fewer steps than a regular knot.

Comment: Though this does technically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) if you could explain the essential parts of the links that you've provided.

Answer (score 1):

Apply a couple coats of clear nail polish (cheaper) or silicone seal to raw edges within holes ... after cleaning them to de-oil/dirt. U will have to redo as it wears off of course.

Answer (score 0):

When you pull it the laces tight, pull them straight out from the hole (i.e. outwards from the shoe) as opposed to upwards (or 90 degrees from the hole).
This will help limit the friction applied to the holes from the laces and hence help prevent rippage.

Comment: You mean to reduce whatever friction is created. You can't eliminate the phenomenon. It's physics. I'm not sure I clearly understand your answer. It might be just me.

Comment: @Stan If you pull straight out it is just going through the middle of the hole.  If you pull at a 90 degree angle you are create maximum friction.

Comment: Please edit your answer to provide more detail and clarity. It's vague.

Comment: @Stan See the lace in the picture.  It comes out of hole and makes 90 turn.    Pull straight out like you were pulling the lace to you nose.  Then hold the tension and cross for the tie.

Answer (score 0):

You could reinforce the rim of the hole, inside and out, with Shoe Goop or even clear nail polish (though not as effective).

BTW, some grommets have sharp edges, which tear laces.